# Problem loading data using PDO: encoding error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, pdo

I want to load some data from sql table into my page. This is the php script that I am using:

**PHP:**

```
<?php

include_once "conectar.php";
header('Content-Type: text/txt; charset=utf-8');

public class Calendario{
    public function cargarCalendarios() {
        $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=practica_db;charset=utf8","root","");
        $sql = "SELECT nombre, descripcion, likes FROM calendarios";

            $pdo = $conexion->prepare($sql);
            $pdo->execute();

        $json = array();

        while ($row=$pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $json[] = array('nombre' =>$row['nombre'], 'descripcion'=>$row['descripcion'], 'likes'=>$row['likes']);
            }
                echo json_encode($json);
        }
    }

    ($calendario = new Calendario())->cargarCalendarios();

?>
```

I am calling that script here:

**JS:**

```
function cargarCalendarios() {

  $.ajax({
    url: '../php/menuCalendarios.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
  })
.done(function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(id,value){
           //code
        }
  });
    })
  .fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
   //...More error handling
   } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
  });

 }
```

I get an error in the request, and I don't know what I am doing wrong. The error must be in the PHP code I asume, but I just can't find anything. 
If it helps, I am working in a local server with XAMPP.
I always get failure and the alert:
`'Requested JSON parse failed.'`

Comment: Don't guess. Open you browser developer tools and have a look at the exact response. I bet it's an HTML error message.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I am using the browser. I am not getting any errors. It just triggers the .fail() always. But I will check the HTML just in case.

Comment: Do you mean time out or connection refused?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, neither. I am getting textStatus === 'parsererror', always triggering the .fail()

Comment: Do you need help to find the browser developer tools?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, yes, I am using Atom and the browser tools, but I think that is not a goog setup. I am new to php, thank you!

Comment: I presume you're using Chrome. Hit `F12` in your keyboard, then click on the "Network" tab. Make sure either "All" or "XHR" are selected.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, that part I think is working. I get: Status 200

Comment: Now, get back to my first suggestion. What's the response body?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, oh, I see, I was having trouble debuggin php code. It was a syntax error in the php